# Higher API calls when lower SDK targeted

Tags: android

My app supports minSdkVersion=10 and targeting 16. I want to call methods specific to API level >= 14 if a specific device supports them. I could check running OS version at runtime and whether call or not higher API methods but when I specify min SDK version, methods that exist only in versions higher than 10 are not visible. 
Is there any way to use higher API methods than minSdkVersion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods from higher API are invisible and inaccessible because project's  target SDK is lower than SDK which methods are going to be used. For example: if you want to use methods from API 14 Android project target SDK should be at least 14 or even better the latest (currently 16). That is kind of obvious but I missed it. After that the solution Sam gave a reference to is in use.

Answer (score 12):

You can test the device's API with this:

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
    // Do something fancy
}
else {
    // Do something regular
}
```

Comment: This is what I mentioned. I can check the OS version but methods specific only for SDK higher then 10 are inaccessible. //Do something will fail build, because method that exists only in SDK 14 or higher is undefined for SDK 10.

Comment: Ok, here's the blog entry from Android discussing the concept in detail: [How to have your (Cup)cake and eat it too](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html)

Comment: Up vote. Blog post gave me idea why higher API methods are invisible in my code. Answer is simply target highest SDK in project properties.

Answer (score 5):

In addition of checking the current version you should also add `@SuppressLint("NewApi")`to your method so the compiler want yell about it.