# Can we download a payment application that uses HCE in phones with lower than Android Kit-Kat 4.4.x?

Tags: android, android-manifest, nfc, hce, manifest-merging

I understand from the official android web site  https://developer.android.com/about/versions/kitkat.html which says that "*Android 4.4 introduces new platform support for secure NFC-based transactions through Host Card Emulation (HCE), for payments,...*" that we can not use HCE in the devices lower than Android Kit-Kat 4.4.x.

But I want to ask if we can *download* an Android application which uses/contains HCE and its related classes on the device which has a version that lower than *Android Kit-Kat 4.4.x*?

My project manifest file has `android:minSdkVersion="14"` and `android:targetSdkVersion="21"` but the HCE SDK used by my project's manifest has `android:minSdkVersion="19"` and `android:targetSdkVersion="21"`. So does my project actually have `android:minSdkVersion` set to 14 or 19?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Can I *download* an application that makes use of HCE functionality to a pre-KitKat device?

Yes, if your application specifies a `android:minSdkVersion` lower than 19 (Android 4.4) and if your application does not *require* the HCE feature (i.e. if you don't specify

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc.hce" android:required="true" />
```

in the application manifest).

#### What if any of the libraries that I use sets a higher `android:minSdkVersion`?

In that case, builing your application should fail. The manifest merger tools is supposed to discover the mismatch between your application's `android:minSdkVersion` and your library dependencies' `android:minSdkVersion` attributes. However, you could override this by explicitly overriding the SDK requirements of specific libraries with something like this:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="19"
          tools:overrideLibrary="package.name.of.the.library" />
```

When using this, your application will be able to target a lower API version. However, if the library makes use of API calls that are not part of a device's API version, these calls will lead to errors/exceptions.

#### What if any of the libraries that I use sets the `android:required` attribute for the HCE feature?

In that case, all `android:required` attributes are combined with logical *OR*. Hence, if one manifest indicates that the HCE feature is required, your wholöe application will require that attribute. Consequently, the application won't be available for pre-KitKat devices (e.g. Play Store will only list it for devices that have the HCE feature, which effectively limits availability to devices with Android 4.4+).

#### Does it even make sense to have an application that uses HCE available for pre-KitKat devices?

That depends on the functionality of your app. HCE won't work on pre-KitKat devices. Hence, if HCE is the core component of your app and the app won't be useful without it, then it does not make sense to have the app available for pre-KitKat devices.

However, if the app can switch to other communication mechanisms for pre-KitKat devices (e.g. inverse reader mode, peer-to-peer mode, QR codes/barcodes), then it could make sense to have a `android:minSdkVersion` lower than 19 (and to mark the HCE feature as optional with `android:required="false"`) in order to make your app available for pre-KitKat devices.

Answer (score 2):

I think Host Card Emulation (HCE) required driver/lower level framework changes. So if the device supported HCE below KitKat (4.4) it probably is something special the device manufacturer put in, similar to how only with Marshmallow (6.0) has Fingerprint Reader API but Samsung had a API for using it in their SDK for their devices.

TL;DR: Without a common API provided by the Android framework any such app would need to implement each vendor's SDK for NFC HCE and then only work for those devices which support each vendor's SDK.

Comment: My project manifest file has android:minSdkVersion="14" and android:targetSdkVersion="21" but the HCE SDK used by my project's manifest has android:minSdkVersion="19" and android:targetSdkVersion="21". So does my project actually have minSdkVersion 14 or 19?

Comment: For the HCE feature you'll need to running on a SDK 19 device. If your app will work below that depends on if its a critical feature for your app or not. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749972/higher-api-calls-when-lower-sdk-targeted

Comment: If my app doesn't have that critiacal feature, a device lower than versiyon 19 can not download my app, am I understand right?

Comment: By critical feature I mean your app makes no sense without it. You can have a payment app where HCE is just one of the methods. If HCE is a must then you are limited to API 19 and up.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand better now.