# Unable to authenticate with google play services on samsung S6, S7 [Starting Auth Transition. Op: SIGN_IN status: ERROR_NOT_AUTHORIZED]

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, authentication, google-play-services

I use Google Play Services for my game and my game is on production. Everything works fine on my Nexus and many others Android. But on samsung s6, s7 and s8 players can't load scenes. I debug with adb logcat and I found this problem of authentication. I followed many steps on Google but most of the time developers have this issue during bêta test.

Please help me, I spent many days trying to correct it.

My log output :

```
07-31 21:11:45.374  2622  2640 W GamesServiceBroker: Client connected with SDK 10260000, Services 11055470, and Games 36250070
07-31 21:11:45.375  2622  2640 W GamesServiceBroker: Rejecting connection - api version 6 is too high
07-31 21:11:45.379 10894 10894 V GamesNativeSDK: Play Games callback indicates connection failure.
07-31 21:11:45.381 10894 10991 I GamesNativeSDK: UI interaction required to connect to Google Play.
07-31 21:11:45.390 10894 10991 I GamesNativeSDK: Auth operation started: SIGN IN
07-31 21:11:45.390 10894 10991 I GamesNativeSDK: Connecting to Google Play...
07-31 21:11:45.409  2622  2638 W GamesServiceBroker: Client connected with SDK 10260000, Services 11055470, and Games 36250070
07-31 21:11:45.409  2622  2638 W GamesServiceBroker: Rejecting connection - api version 6 is too high
07-31 21:11:45.414 10894 10894 V GamesNativeSDK: Play Games callback indicates connection failure.
07-31 21:11:45.415 10894 10991 I GamesNativeSDK: UI interaction required to connect to Google Play.
07-31 21:11:45.415 10894 10991 I GamesNativeSDK: Resolving connection.
07-31 21:11:45.415  1689 10585 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=com.google.android.gms.games.PLAY_GAMES_UPGRADE pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.games.PlayGamesUpgradeActivity (has extras)} from uid 10014 on display 0
07-31 21:11:45.436 10894 10939 I Unity   :  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 07/31/17 21:11:45 +00:00 DEBUG: Activating PlayGamesPlatform.
07-31 21:11:45.436 10894 10939 I Unity   :
07-31 21:11:45.436 10894 10939 I Unity   : (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)
07-31 21:11:45.436 10894 10939 I Unity   :
07-31 21:11:45.437 10894 10939 I Unity   :  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 07/31/17 21:11:45 +00:00 DEBUG: Instance was not initialized, using default configuration.
07-31 21:11:45.437 10894 10939 I Unity   :
07-31 21:11:45.437 10894 10939 I Unity   : (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)
07-31 21:11:45.437 10894 10939 I Unity   :
07-31 21:11:45.437 10894 10939 W Unity   : !!! [Play Games Plugin DLL] 07/31/17 21:11:45 +00:00 WARNING: Creating new PlayGamesPlatform
07-31 21:11:45.437 10894 10939 W Unity   :
07-31 21:11:45.437 10894 10939 W Unity   : (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)
07-31 21:11:45.437 10894 10939 W Unity   :
07-31 21:11:45.437 10894 10939 I Unity   :  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 07/31/17 21:11:45 +00:00 DEBUG: PlayGamesPlatform activated: GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform
07-31 21:11:45.437 10894 10939 I Unity   :
07-31 21:11:45.437 10894 10939 I Unity   : (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)
07-31 21:11:45.437 10894 10939 I Unity   :
07-31 21:11:45.437 10894 10939 I Unity   :  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 07/31/17 21:11:45 +00:00 DEBUG: Activating PlayGamesPlatform.
07-31 21:11:45.437 10894 10939 I Unity   :
07-31 21:11:45.437 10894 10939 I Unity   : (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)
07-31 21:11:45.437 10894 10939 I Unity   :
07-31 21:11:45.437 10894 10939 I Unity   :  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 07/31/17 21:11:45 +00:00 DEBUG: PlayGamesPlatform activated: GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform
07-31 21:11:45.437 10894 10939 I Unity   :
07-31 21:11:45.437 10894 10939 I Unity   : (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)
07-31 21:11:45.437 10894 10939 I Unity   :
07-31 21:11:45.437 10894 10939 I Unity   :  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 07/31/17 21:11:45 +00:00 DEBUG: Creating platform-specific Play Games client.
07-31 21:11:45.437 10894 10939 I Unity   :
07-31 21:11:45.437 10894 10939 I Unity   : (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)
07-31 21:11:45.437 10894 10939 I Unity   :
07-31 21:11:45.437 10894 10939 I Unity   :  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 07/31/17 21:11:45 +00:00 DEBUG: Creating Android IPlayGamesClient Client
07-31 21:11:45.437 10894 10939 I Unity   :
07-31 21:11:45.437 10894 10939 I Unity   : (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)
07-31 21:11:45.437 10894 10939 I Unity   :
07-31 21:11:45.437 10894 10939 I Unity   :  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 07/31/17 21:11:45 +00:00 DEBUG: Activating PlayGamesPlatform.
07-31 21:11:45.437 10894 10939 I Unity   :
07-31 21:11:45.437 10894 10939 I Unity   : (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)
07-31 21:11:45.437 10894 10939 I Unity   :
07-31 21:11:45.438 10894 10939 I Unity   :  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 07/31/17 21:11:45 +00:00 DEBUG: PlayGamesPlatform activated: GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform
07-31 21:11:45.438 10894 10939 I Unity   :
07-31 21:11:45.438 10894 10939 I Unity   : (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)
07-31 21:11:45.438 10894 10939 I Unity   :
07-31 21:11:45.438 10894 10939 I Unity   :  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 07/31/17 21:11:45 +00:00 DEBUG: Starting Auth Transition. Op: SIGN_IN status: ERROR_NOT_AUTHORIZED
07-31 21:11:45.438 10894 10939 I Unity   :
07-31 21:11:45.438 10894 10939 I Unity   : (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)
07-31 21:11:45.438 10894 10939 I Unity   :
07-31 21:11:45.438 10894 10939 I Unity   :  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 07/31/17 21:11:45 +00:00 DEBUG: Invoking callbacks, AuthState changed from silentPending to Unauthenticated.
07-31 21:11:45.438 10894 10939 I Unity   :
07-31 21:11:45.438 10894 10939 I Unity   : (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)
07-31 21:11:45.438 10894 10939 I Unity   :
07-31 21:11:45.438 10894 10939 I Unity   :  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 07/31/17 21:11:45 +00:00 DEBUG: there are pending auth callbacks - starting AuthUI
07-31 21:11:45.438 10894 10939 I Unity   :
07-31 21:11:45.438 10894 10939 I Unity   : (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)
07-31 21:11:45.438 10894 10939 I Unity   :
07-31 21:11:45.576  9655  9655 E ChimeraProxyRslvr: Chimera config error: com.google.android.chimera.config.InvalidConfigException: No registered Chimera impl for ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.games.PlayGamesUpgradeActivity}
07-31 21:11:45.583  1689  1992 W InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@942928d attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@929f4e2
07-31 21:11:45.593 10894 10894 V GamesNativeSDK: Received Activity Resume Event.
07-31 21:11:45.603  2622  2935 W GamesServiceBroker: Client connected with SDK 10260000, Services 11055470, and Games 36250070
07-31 21:11:45.605  2622  2935 W GamesServiceBroker: Rejecting connection - api version 6 is too high
07-31 21:11:45.607 10894 10939 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x7d71ed80: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x7e123290)
07-31 21:11:45.612 10894 10993 D AudioTrack: Client defaulted notificationFrames to 682 for frameCount 2048
07-31 21:11:45.620 10894 10894 V GamesNativeSDK: Play Games callback indicates connection failure.
07-31 21:11:45.621 10894 10991 I GamesNativeSDK: UI interaction required to connect to Google Play.
07-31 21:11:45.628 10894 10939 I Unity   :  [Play Games Plugin DLL] 07/31/17 21:11:45 +00:00 DEBUG: Application is pausing, which disconnects the RTMP  client.  Leaving room.
07-31 21:11:45.628 10894 10939 I Unity   :
07-31 21:11:45.628 10894 10939 I Unity   : (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)
07-31 21:11:45.628 10894 10939 I Unity   :
07-31 21:11:46.624  2622  2934 W GamesServiceBroker: Client connected with SDK 10260000, Services 11055470, and Games 36250070
07-31 21:11:46.625  2622  2934 W GamesServiceBroker: Rejecting connection - api version 6 is too high
07-31 21:11:46.627 10894 10894 V GamesNativeSDK: Play Games callback indicates connection failure.
07-31 21:11:46.627 10894 10991 I GamesNativeSDK: UI interaction required to connect to Google Play.
```

My gradle

```
// GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
      flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
      }
   }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(name: 'common', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'customtabs-24.0.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'GoogleAIDL', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'GooglePlay', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'onesignal-unity', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-auth-11.0.4', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-auth-base-11.0.4', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-base-11.0.4', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-basement-11.0.4', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-drive-11.0.4', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-games-11.0.4', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-gcm-11.0.4', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-iid-11.0.4', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-location-11.0.4', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-nearby-11.0.4', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'play-services-tasks-11.0.4', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'support-compat-25.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'support-core-ui-25.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'support-core-utils-25.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'support-fragment-25.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'support-media-compat-25.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'support-v4-25.2.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'UnityAds', ext:'aar')
    compile project(':answers')
    compile project(':beta')
    compile project(':crashlytics')
    compile project(':crashlytics-wrapper')
    compile project(':fabric')
    compile project(':fabric-init')
    compile project(':MainLibProj')
    compile project(':OneSignalConfig')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 24
        applicationId 'com.masseka.game.studio'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    signingConfigs { release {
        storeFile file('keystore')
        storePassword 'mdp'
        keyAlias 'kosted'
        keyPassword 'mdp'
    } }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            jniDebuggable true
        }
        release {
            // Set minifyEnabled to true if you want to run ProGuard on your project
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

}
```

My AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.masseka.game.studio" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:versionName="1.0.0" android:versionCode="57" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="io.fabric.unity.android.FabricApplication" android:isGame="true">
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection" android:name="com.masseka.game.studio.UnityPlayerActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDialogsActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityAppLinkActivity" android:exported="true" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityDeepLinkingActivity" android:exported="true" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityGameRequestActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityCreateGameGroupActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityJoinGameGroupActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.unity.AppInviteDialogActivity" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="fb861561667323639" />
    <!--<provider android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider861561667323639" android:exported="true" />-->
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="24" />
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.vulkan" android:required="false" />
  <supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your [android:targetSdkVersion](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html) in your gradle file does not support the higher versions of Android API which is apparent in your error

```
api version 6 is too high
```

Try changing your `android:targetSdkVersion` to 25 which supports Android 7 (Nougat).

Check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749972/higher-api-calls-when-lower-sdk-targeted) for additional reference.

Comment: My maximum target is Android 7.0 (Api level 24) Nougat and the minimum 4.1 (Api level 16) Jelly bean